# Ramda - Map over array of partially nested objects and modify the property

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array of objects:

```
const data = [
{id: 1, date: {month: {value: 6, label: "June"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}},
{id: 2, date: {month: {value: 7, label: "July"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}}
]
```

I need to map over the array and combine the values for the date so it would look like this:

```
const data = [
{id: 1, date: "June, 2022"},
{id: 2, date: "July, 2022"}
]
```

I would like to use Ramda. I can map over the array, however, I am not sure how to combine nested objects and make it a string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
data.map((e) => {
  const date = `${e.date.month.label}, ${e.date.year.label}`;
  return {
    id: e.id,
    date: date,
  };
});
```

This should work.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: OK. Thanks Scott. Im new to coding. Honeslty wasnt even sure if I was answering the question correctly.

Comment: It's not a problem.  Your code looks fine.  It's also similar to how I'd do it.  But it would help if you could [edit] to add a bit more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array to new object by evolving the `date` to the new form:

```js
const { map, evolve, pipe, props, pluck, join } = R

const fn = map(evolve({
  date: pipe(
    props(['month', 'year']), // get an array of month and year objects
    pluck('label'), // extract the labels
    join(', ') // join to a string
  )
}))

const data = [
{id: 1, date: {month: {value: 6, label: "June"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}}},
{id: 2, date: {month: {value: 7, label: "July"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}}}
]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And combined with the nice simplicity of [Fishamble answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74132560/5157454):

```js
const { map, evolve } = R

const fn = map(evolve({
  date: ({ month, year }) => `${month.label}, ${year.label}`
}))

const data = [
{id: 1, date: {month: {value: 6, label: "June"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}}},
{id: 2, date: {month: {value: 7, label: "July"}, year: {value: 2022, label: "2022"}}}
]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```